# Why can the group of isomorphism classes of line bundles be identified with $H^1(C,\mathbb O_C^*)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, self-learning, vector-bundles

This is a reference request to the fact in the title. Is there a book at most as advanced as Hartshorn's which explains this result?

Comment: You are asking why $\operatorname{Pic} X = H^1 (X,\mathcal{O}_X^\ast)$? This has to be proven somewhere in Hartshorne.

Comment: @fppf It is (of course) an exercise in Hartshorne.

Comment: Also, if you realize that every line bundle is determined by a 1-cocycle (which is immediate from the definition), what's left is to check what happens to the coboundaries.